# Scraping product information with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Below given is my entire code. I'm facing some errors while running this code. Please help me out with my code. I want the Product category, product sub-category, and product name printed side by side in a dataframe.

```
key = ['for-babies','beauty','hair','skin','body','gift-packs']
data_main = []
for x in tqdm(key):
    r=requests.get(f'https://mamaearth.in/product-category/{x}', headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    category = soup.find('a',class_='active').text.strip()
    sub_category = soup.find('a',class_='SubText-sc-8mwtwz-0 ieXHku').text.strip()
    pro_name=soup.find('div',class_='title').text.strip()
    data_main.append({
        'Category':category,
        'Sub_category':sub_category,
        'Pro_Name':pro_name,
    })
df=pd.DataFrame(data_main)
df
```

Comment: I think you should also provide some detailed information about "some errors" you're facing. It's really difficult to understand the root cause without the error itself.

Comment: I have no clue what you are doing in your code, but I'd assume that if you're using `for x in tqdm(key)`, and `key` has exctly 6 elements, that might be the issue here.

Comment: Okay, I see. You are navigating through **sections**. Then in each section you look for exactly one (first) product by running `pro_name=soup.find('div',class_='title').text.strip()`. Now instead of that, you should find all such occurrences (might be by using `find_all` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all), and then loop through the resulting array by introducing another loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will returrn a dataframe for each page w/ products. You can then further combine dataframes into one, etc, the whole point of my answer is putting you on the right path:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import json

headers = {

    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
keys = ['for-babies','beauty','hair','skin','body','gift-packs']
for x in tqdm(keys):
    r=requests.get(f'https://mamaearth.in/product-category/{x}', headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    data_script = soup.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
    json_obj = json.loads(data_script.text)
    try:
        df = pd.json_normalize(json_obj['itemListElement'])
        print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print(x, e)
```

This would print in terminal:

|  | @type | position | item.@type | item.name | item.image | item.description | item.url | item.sku | item.mpn | item.brand.@type | item.brand.name | item.offers.@type | item.offers.url | item.offers.priceCurrency | item.offers.price | item.offers.priceValidUntil | item.offers.itemCondition | item.offers.availability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ListItem | 0 | Product | Coco Soft Body Wash For Babies With Coconut Milk & Turmeric - 400 ml | https://honasa-mamaearth-production.imgix.net/c/o/coco-bw-1.jpg | Coco Soft Body Wash For Babies With Coconut Milk & Turmeric - 400 ml | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-body-wash-for-babies-with-coconut-milk-turmeric-400-ml | 8904417300635 | 1660043236909 | Brand | Mamaearth | Offer | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-body-wash-for-babies-with-coconut-milk-turmeric-400-ml | INR | 449 | 2024-08-09 | https://schema.org/NewCondition | https://schema.org/InStock |
| 1 | ListItem | 1 | Product | Coco Soft Body Lotion with Coconut Milk & Turmeric for 24-Hour Moisturization - 400 ml | https://honasa-mamaearth-production.imgix.net/c/o/coco_soft_body_lotion_1.jpg | Coco Soft Body Lotion with Coconut Milk & Turmeric for 24-Hour Moisturization - 400 ml | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-body-lotion-with-coconut-milk-turmeric-for-24-hour-moisturization-400-ml | 8904417300628 | 1660043236909 | Brand | Mamaearth | Offer | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-body-lotion-with-coconut-milk-turmeric-for-24-hour-moisturization-400-ml | INR | 449 | 2024-08-09 | https://schema.org/NewCondition | https://schema.org/InStock |
| 2 | ListItem | 2 | Product | Coco Soft Bathing Bar for Babies with Coconut Oil & Turmeric for Babies - Pack of 2*75g | https://honasa-mamaearth-production.imgix.net/c/o/coco-bar-1.jpg | Coco Soft Bathing Bar for Babies with Coconut Oil & Turmeric for Babies - Pack of 2*75g | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-bathing-bar-for-babies-with-coconut-oil-turmeric-for-babies-pack-of-2-75g | 8904417300659 | 1660043236909 | Brand | Mamaearth | Offer | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-bathing-bar-for-babies-with-coconut-oil-turmeric-for-babies-pack-of-2-75g | INR | 249 | 2024-08-09 | https://schema.org/NewCondition | https://schema.org/InStock |
| 3 | ListItem | 3 | Product | Coco Soft Massage Oil with Coconut & Turmeric Oil for Babies - 200 ml | https://honasa-mamaearth-production.imgix.net/c/o/coco-oil-1.jpg | Coco Soft Massage Oil with Coconut & Turmeric Oil for Babies - 200 ml | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-massage-oil-with-coconut-turmeric-oil-for-babies-200-ml | 8904417300666 | 1660043236909 | Brand | Mamaearth | Offer | https://mamaearth.in/product/coco-soft-massage-oil-with-coconut-turmeric-oil-for-babies-200-ml | INR | 399 | 2024-08-09 | https://schema.org/NewCondition | https://schema.org/InStock |

[...]